# How to obtain and store centroid coordinates of rooms of a floor plan image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a floor plan image which consists of multiple rooms. Using Python, I want to find the centers of each room and store the coordinates in the form of (x,y) so that I can use them further for mathematical calculations. The existing `drawContours` and `FindContours` functions help in determining the contours, but how can I store the values obtained into a list.

The image represents a sample floor plan with multiple rooms.

[image: The image represents a sample floor plan with multiple rooms.]

I tried using `moments` but the function doesn't work properly.
[As you may see this image is obtained from `drawContours` function. But then how do I store the x and y coordinates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWl5H.png)

Here's my code :

```
k= []
# Going through every contours found in the image. 
for cnt in contours : 

    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.009 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True) 

    # draws boundary of contours. 
    cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], -1, (0, 0,255), 3)  

    # Used to flatted the array containing 
    # the co-ordinates of the vertices. 
    n = approx.ravel()  
    i = 0
    x=[]
    y=[]

    for j in n : 
        if(i % 2 == 0): 
            x = n[i] 
            y = n[i + 1]



            # String containing the co-ordinates. 
            string = str(x) + " ," + str(y)  


            if(i == 0): 
                # text on topmost co-ordinate. 
                cv2.putText(img, string, (x, y), 
                                font, 0.5, (255, 0, 0))
                k.append(str((x, y))) 


            else: 
                # text on remaining co-ordinates. 
                cv2.putText(img, string, (x, y),  
                          font, 0.5, (0, 255, 0))  
                k.append(str((x, y)))

        i = i + 1


# Showing the final image. 
cv2_imshow( img )  
# Exiting the window if 'q' is pressed on the keyboard. 
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You say moments do not work. But you do not show your code. please always provide your code, so that others can see if you have an error. Once you have the contours, you can get the bounding boxes, from which you can easily computer the centers.

Comment: No for moments, it gives ZeroDivisionError. That's why I didn't include it

Comment: You still do not show your code for the centroids. Given valid contours, you should be able to get the centroids from:  `  M = cv2.moments(cntr)
  cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
  cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])   
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** Load image, grayscale, and [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization).
2. **Remove text.** We [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) then filter using [contour area](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea) to remove contours smaller than some threshold value. We effectively remove these contours by filling them in with [`cv2.drawContours`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#how-to-draw-the-contours).
3. **Find rectangular boxes and obtain centroid coordinates.** We find contours again then filter using contour area and [contour approximation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html). We then find moments for each contour which gives us the [centroid](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html).

---

Here's a visualization:

Remove text

[image]

Result

[image]

Coordinates

```
[(93, 241), (621, 202), (368, 202), (571, 80), (317, 79), (93, 118)]
```

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove text
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 1000:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, 0, -1)

thresh = 255 - thresh
result = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
coordinates = []

# Find rectangular boxes and obtain centroid coordinates
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4 and area < 100000:
        # cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 1)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        coordinates.append((cx, cy))
        cv2.circle(result, (cx, cy), 3, (36,255,12), -1)
        cv2.putText(result, '({}, {})'.format(int(cx), int(cy)), (int(cx) -40, int(cy) -10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (36,255,12), 2)

print(coordinates)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```